# SQL most effective query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating two queries on the 3 tables below and I just want someone's opinion on if I'm executing them most effectively.

```
User (**user_id**, group, age, gender, timestamp, activity_type)

Client (**client_id**, sector, specified_age, specified_gender)

Advertise (a**d_id, user_id, client_id, time**, is_click, length)
```

Which client sector had the most advertisement clicks?

```
 SELECT c.client_id, c.sector, COUNT(a.is_click) as Clicked_Ads 
    FROM Advertise a, Client c
    WHERE a.client_id = c.client_id
    GROUP BY COUNT(a.is_click)
    ORDER BY c.client_id
```

What time are women most frequently watching advertisements?

```
 SELECT a.ad_id, a.client_id, u.user_id, u.timestamps, COUNT(u.timestamps)
    FROM Advertise a, User u
    WHERE u.gender = “Female”, a.user_id = u.user_id
    ORDER BY 
    GROUP BY COUNT(u.timestamps

)
```

Comment: What is the RDBMS? it is mysql or sql-server? remove one tag

Comment: fixed it to sql-server - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query should look like this:

```
SELECT c.sector, COUNT(a.is_click) as Clicked_Ads 
FROM Advertise a JOIN
     Client c
     ON a.client_id = c.client_id
GROUP BY c.sector
ORDER BY COUNT(a.is_click) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Notes:

- Use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- The question is about `sector`, nothing else is needed in the `GROUP BY` clause.
- You cannot `GROUP BY` an aggregation function anyway.
- Presumably you want the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1` to get the top sector.

One question is enough for a question.

Answer (score 0):

To find client sector with most clicks across all clients, for MS SQL server

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES client_id,sector, Clicked_Ads 
 (
   SELECT c.client_id, c.sector, SUM(a.is_click) as Clicked_Ads 
    FROM Advertise a JOIN Client c
    ON a.client_id = c.client_id
    GROUP BY c.client_id, c.sector
  )T
ORDER BY Clicked_Ads  DESC
```